# Calculating weight on Saturn and Jupiter

Tags: java

I have this code

```
public class Operator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //This part of the code is about my weight on earth.
        System.out.print("My weight on earth is ");
        double mWOE = 66.2;

        //mWOE = myWheightOnEarth
        System.out.println(mWOE);

        //This part of the code is about my weight on jupiter.
        System.out.print("My weight on jupiter is ");
        double mWOJ = mWOE * 2.54;

        //mWOJ = myWheightOnJupiter
        System.out.println(mWOJ);

        //This part of the code is about my wheight on saturn
        System.out.print("My weight on saturn is ");
        double mWOS = mWOE * 1.08;

        //mWOS = myWheightOnSaturn
        System.out.println(mWOS);
    }

}
```

I want to make my program get the weight and give weight on Saturn and Jupiter. What should i do to the code?

P.S: It's in java.

Comment: you want to read input from keyboard?

Comment: It's terribly unclear what you're asking.  You are already outputting the calculated weights, what else are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get input from keyboard, use the `Scanner` class. Try this:

```
System.out.print("My weight on earth is ");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
double mWOE = 0.0;
if (s.hasNextDouble()){
    mWOE = s.nextDouble();
}
```

And then, the remaining code is the same.

Comment: Thanks dude. Really helped Now I got the program I was Wishing to make. :)